# I'd like an explanation of some behavior in Ruby that I ran across in the Koans

Tags: ruby

Why does the second assert_equal below work?  How does ruby associate "dos" with :two?

```
  def test_default_value

    hash2 = Hash.new("dos")
    hash2[:one] = 1

    assert_equal 1, hash2[:one]
    assert_equal "dos", hash2[:two]
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument to `Hash.new` is the "default" value - when a key isn't present, and is read, return that value instead.  You can also pass a block to `Hash.new` to have more complex behaviour around default values.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-c-new

Comment: Also note that it returns the same value each time, so using a default value of a string (which is mutable) is unwise. At the very least, you'd want to freeze it.